# I am trying to check if every element of one array is in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using the below code to verify if every element of one array is present in another array.

```
     let expected_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner","this","Edit","Delete","Sharing","MI/User Reg",
     "Convert","Disqualify","Email Preferences"]

     let actual_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner","Edit","Delete","Sharing","MI/User Reg",
     "Convert","Disqualify","Email Preferences"]

   try{ 
    if(expected_ActionLinks.some(async (element)=>{ actual_ActionLinks.indexOf(element) > -1 }))
    {
        console.log("All action links are present on the page")
        return true
    } else{

        console.log("All action links are present on the page")
        return false 
    }
}
```

I am trying to verify if every element of one array is present in the other array.
For example here - every element of expected_ActionLinks should be present in actual_ActionLinks. If yes, it will return true, if no it will return false.

The problem here is the above code returns always true irrespective of any situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .every of Array

**For same**

```js
let expected_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner", "Edit", "Delete", "Sharing", "MI/User Reg", "Convert", "Disqualify", "Email Preferences"];

let actual_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner", "Edit", "Delete", "Sharing", "MI/User Reg", "Convert", "Disqualify", "Email Preferences"];

const isSame = expected_ActionLinks.every(item => actual_ActionLinks.includes(item));

console.log(isSame);
```

**For not same**

```js
let expected_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner", "this", "Edit", "Delete", "Sharing", "MI/User Reg", "Convert", "Disqualify", "Email Preferences"];

let actual_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner", "Edit", "Delete", "Sharing", "MI/User Reg", "Convert", "Disqualify", "Email Preferences"];

const isSame = expected_ActionLinks.every(item => actual_ActionLinks.includes(item));

console.log(isSame);
```

Comment: I tried every method of array in js. It also returns true instead of false. If u notice both the list do not have same element so it should return true but it returns false. I have used some, every, json.stringify None of them work properly

Comment: @Sndeep isSame is false because both list are not same, once its same it will be true, please check updated code

Comment: @Sndeep updated answer: For same : isSame = true and  For not same : isSame = false

Answer (score 0):

Remove `async` add `return`

```js
function check() {
  let expected_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner", "this", "Edit", "Delete", "Sharing", "MI/User Reg",
    "Convert", "Disqualify", "Email Preferences"
  ]

  let actual_ActionLinks = ["Add to Call List", "ChangeOwner", "Edit", "Delete", "Sharing", "MI/User Reg",
    "Convert", "Disqualify", "Email Preferences"
  ]

  if (expected_ActionLinks.some((element) => {
      return actual_ActionLinks.indexOf(element) > -1
    })) {

    console.log("All action links are present on the page")
    return true
  } else {

    console.log("All action links are present on the page")
    return false

  }
}

check()
```

Comment: Removed async and added return however it still returns true. It should return false as both the list have different elements.